# Searching for a value in an HTML table and change its TD value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the click of a button, after entering a number value in the number input box, the javascript function should search for the matching value of the number box in the HTML table and then change the TD cell values to whatever the user inputs in the other 2 input boxes (color and item).

I've put some html coding below as to what I am trying to accomplish. I am jQuery friendly if that the easier route to use as I am not a skilled enough programmer myself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>           
</head>
<body>
Number:*
<input type="text" id="number">
<br>

Items:
<input type="text" id="item">
<br>

Color:
<input type="text" id="color">
<br>    
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="changeit()" value="save">
<br>

<table id="data" style="width: 100%" cellspacing="1" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Number*</b></td>
        <td><b>items</b></td>
        <td><b>Colors</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>Boats</td>
        <td>red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>456</td>
        <td>Vehicles</td>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>789</td>
        <td>Motorcycles</td>
        <td>green</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show what you currently have for the `changeit()` function?

Comment: Pro-tip: instead of doing `<tr><td><b>some header</b></td></tr>`, just do `<th><td>some header</td></th>`. That way, browsers should automatically add bolding, and you have the semantic value of showing that it's the header and not actual data.

Comment: Re: oxguy3's comment, you should also wrap your header in a `<thead>` and your body in a `<tbody>`.  I believe browsers will do that for you implicitly, but it's better to be explicit.  It makes it more apparent in source what the structure will ultimately render like too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/c84doLdm/

Relevant code (uses jQuery) is here:

```
function changeit() {
    var valueToFind = $('#number').val();
    $('#data > tbody> tr').each(function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        var firstTd = $(this).find('td:first');
        if ($(firstTd).text() == valueToFind) {
            console.log("found: " + index + ":" + valueToFind);
            $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text($('#item').val());
            $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text($('#color').val());
        }
    })
}
```

You might want to remove the `console.log()` statements, and improve the efficiency a bit by caching DOM values, but that's the gist of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some jQuery pseudocode that broadly does what you want to do:

```
var number = $("#number").val(); // get the number the user entered
var numberCell = $("td:contains('" + number + "')"); // get a reference to the <td> tag with the same number as the one the user typed in
var row = numberCell.parent(); // get a reference to the <tr> tag that `numberCell` is inside of

var itemCell = row.children()[1]; // get a reference to the item <td>
itemCell.html($("#item").val()); // put the user's item into the item cell

var colorCell = row.children()[2]; // get a reference to the color <td>
colorCell.html($("#color").val()); // put the user's color into the color cell
```

I guess you'll wanna put that in the `changeit()` function. You'll need to add error-checking and stuff (what if the user enters a number that doesn't exist?) but that should get the basic job done.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following code onto yours. That should do the job!

```
<script>
    var table,
        number,
        item,
        color,
        save;

    table = document.getElementById('data');

    number = document.getElementById('number');
    item = document.getElementById('item');
    color = document.getElementById('color');
    save  = document.getElementById('save');

    save.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i){
            if(parseInt(rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML) == parseInt(number.value)){
                rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = item.value;
                rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = color.value;
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```